# Derivative of a function with respect to another function

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerics

I have a question, I would be grateful if someonr helped me.

Suppose I have these functions:

```
te[x_] := x^2
te1[x_] := te[x] x
```

How can I numericaliy differentiate `te1` with respect to `te` — something like

```
D[te1[x], te[x]]
```

and

```
ND[te1[x], te[x]]
```

I know there are much easier ways to obtain these two, but I want to understand the logic of these calculations.

Comment: @ Carl Woll  for numerical too ND??

Comment: You can use `te1'[1.] / te'[1.]` for a numerical derivative at `x=1.`. Note that you need to use machine numbers instead of integers.

Comment: @  Carl Woll  Thanks  But I need some thing with ND

Comment: Is `ND` actually a function? It doesn't seem like it.